# AngularJS $watch newValue is undefined

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to make a alert service with a directive. It is in the directive part I have some trouble. My have a directive that looks like this:

```
angular.module('alertModule').directive('ffAlert', function() {
  return {
    templateUrl: 'components/alert/ff-alert-directive.html',
    controller: ['$scope','alertService',function($scope,alertService) {
      $scope.alerts = alertService;
    }],
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
      scope.$watch(scope.alerts, function (newValue, oldValue) {
        console.log("alerts is now:",scope.alerts,oldValue, newValue);
        for(var i = oldValue.list.length; i < newValue.list.length; i++) {
          scope.alerts.list[i].isVisible = true;
          if (scope.alerts.list[i].timeout > 0) {
            $timeout(function (){
              scope.alerts.list[i].isVisible = false;
            }, scope.alerts.list[i].timeout);
          }
        }
      }, true);
    }
  }
});
```

The reason for the for-loop is to attach a timeout for the alerts that has this specified.

I will also include the directive-template:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <div alert ng-repeat="alert in alerts.list" type="{{alert.type}}" ng-show="alert.isVisible" close="alerts.close(alert.id)">{{alert.msg}}</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
</div>
```

When I run this, I get this error in the console:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'list' of undefined
    at Object.fn (http://localhost:9000/components/alert/ff-alert-directive.js:10:29)
```

10:29 is the dot in "oldValue.list" in the for-loop. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Edit: I am adding the alertService-code (it is a service I use to keep track of all the alerts in my app):

```
angular.module('alertModule').factory('alertService', function() {
  var alerts = {};
  var id = 1;

  alerts.list = [];

  alerts.add = function(alert) {
    alert.id = id;
    alerts.list.push(alert);
    alert.id += 1;
    console.log("alertService.add: ",alert);
    return alert.id;
  };

  alerts.add({type: "info", msg:"Dette er til info...", timeout: 1000});

  alerts.addServerError = function(error) {
    var id = alerts.add({type: "warning", msg: "Errormessage from server: " + error.description});
//    console.log("alertService: Server Error: ", error);
    return id;
  };

  alerts.close = function(id) {
    for(var index = 0; index<alerts.list.length; index += 1) {
      console.log("alert:",index,alerts.list[index].id);
      if (alerts.list[index].id == id) {
        console.log("Heey");
        alerts.list.splice(index, 1);
      }
    }
  };

  alerts.closeAll = function() {
    alerts.list = [];
  };

  return alerts;

});
```

Comment: What is `alertService` ?

Comment: I just added it in the question...

Comment: did you tried to put at the first line of the watcher function before console.log if(newValue === oldValue)  return

Comment: @NarekMamikonyan No, should I do that? Is not the point of the watcher to kick in if there is a new value in the watched object?

Comment: you should, because your watcher fires up at the first time when your directive initalized

Comment: Thats it :) Maybe you could make that an answer I could accept, @NarekMamikonyan?

Comment: done :) good luck :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this , angular fires your watcher  at the first time when your directive initialized

```
angular.module('alertModule').directive('ffAlert', function() {
  return {
    templateUrl: 'components/alert/ff-alert-directive.html',
    controller: ['$scope','alertService',function($scope,alertService) {
      $scope.alerts = alertService;
    }],
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
      scope.$watch(scope.alerts, function (newValue, oldValue) {
        if(newValue === oldValue) return;
        console.log("alerts is now:",scope.alerts,oldValue, newValue);
        for(var i = oldValue.list.length; i < newValue.list.length; i++) {
          scope.alerts.list[i].isVisible = true;
          if (scope.alerts.list[i].timeout > 0) {
            $timeout(function (){
              scope.alerts.list[i].isVisible = false;
            }, scope.alerts.list[i].timeout);
          }
        }
      }, true);
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have jQuery available, try this

```
if(jQuery.isEmptyObject(newValue)){
      return;
}
```

inside `scope.$watch`