# service is returning undefined in the array in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service, angular-promise, angularjs-factory

I am facing trouble with my angularjs script.

Background: I am trying to determine the location of the user, I have written my business logic in my service from where I am returning the location of the user.

Problem : The result I am getting in my console is as below :

> [undefined] landingPage.js:11 undefined landingPage.js:11 undefined

```
var app = angular.module("PublicEvents", ["geolocation"]);

app.controller("iterator", ["$scope", "$http", "locationService1", function($scope, $http, locationService1){
    $scope.targetCity = [];
    $scope.targetCity.push(locationService1.location());

    console.log($scope.targetCity);
    $scope.$watch(function () { return locationService1.cityNameArray; },
            function (value) {
        $scope.targetCity = value;
        console.log($scope.targerCity);
    }
    );

}]);



app.service("locationService1",['$http','$window', function( $http, $window){
    var access = this;
    this.location = function(){
        $window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            access.lat = position.coords.latitude;
            access.long = position.coords.longitude;

            access.locationData = [];
            access.cityNameArray = [];

            /*var url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=18.9750,72.8258&sensor=true";*/
            var url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+access.lat+","+access.long+"&sensor=true";

            //AJAX CALL TO GET THE LOCATION
            $http.get(url).then(function(response) {
                access.locationData = response.data; 
                if(access.locationData.status == "OK" || access.locationData.status==200 ) {
                    angular.forEach(access.locationData.results, function(value, key){
                        var len = value.address_components.length;
                        for(var i = 0; i< len; i++){
                            if(value.address_components[i].types[0] =="locality" || value.address_components[i].types[0] =="sublocality_level_1"){
                                access.cityNameArray.push(value.address_components[i].long_name);
                            }
                        }
                    }); 
                };
            }); 
            return access.cityNameArray;
        });
    };
}]);
```

Comment: what is line 11 in landingPage.js?

Comment: console.log($scope.targerCity); inside $watch

Comment: I think it might be a duplicate of this question then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25575963/angularjs-watch-newvalue-is-undefined

Comment: angular will fire the watcher once when you create it and since nothing was returned from the server yet your value is undefined. Pankaj's answer seems pretty good too. :)

Comment: Let me check the link you have given....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you need to return data from an async call and you are returning value from outside the function. I'd suggest you to use promise pattern in such situation.

```
this.location = function(){
    $window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        access.lat = position.coords.latitude;
        access.long = position.coords.longitude;

        access.locationData = [];
        access.cityNameArray = [];

        /*var url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=18.9750,72.8258&sensor=true";*/
        var url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+access.lat+","+access.long+"&sensor=true";

        //return promise from here..
        return $http.get(url).then(function(response) {
            access.locationData = response.data; 
            if(access.locationData.status == "OK" || access.locationData.status==200 ) {
                angular.forEach(access.locationData.results, function(value, key){
                    var len = value.address_components.length;
                    for(var i = 0; i< len; i++){
                        if(value.address_components[i].types[0] =="locality" || value.address_components[i].types[0] =="sublocality_level_1"){
                            access.cityNameArray.push(value.address_components[i].long_name);
                        }
                    }
                }); 
            };
            return access.cityNameArray; //returned from success callback
        }); 

    });
};
```

Inside controller you need to use `.then` function to get data from the service `loacation` function. You were doing `console.log` when you are doing async call which doesn't return anything.

```
locationService1.location().then(function(data){ //success callback.
   $scope.targetCity.push(data)
},function(error){ //error callback.
   console.log(error)
});
```

Comment: I don't see any promise being returned from the location function.

Comment: @toskv Thanks for your heads up.. I editing my answer.. TYSM

Comment: Is it required to return access.cityNameArray and the promise...Actually I am getting an error cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Comment: @PragamShrivastava yes you need to return both `return $http.get(url).` and `access.cityNameArray`

Comment: It worked after I segregated the navigator function! Thanks :)